# Решето Эратосфена в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Дано число n (n > 1). Выведите строку, состоящую из простых чисел, меньших n. Воспользуйтесь решетом Эратосфена. Единицу не считаем простым числом.

```js
function testCycle(n) {
  var array = [];
  var tmpArray = [];
  var maxPrimeFactor = 0;
  var upperLimit = Math.sqrt(n);
  var output = [];


  for (var i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    array.push(i);
  }

  for (var i = array[0]; i < upperLimit; i = array[0]) {
    removeMultiples: for (var j = i, k = i; j < n; j += i) {
      var index = array.indexOf(j);
      if (index === -1)
        continue removeMultiples;
      else
        array.splice(index, 1);
    }
    tmpArray.push(k);
  }
  array.unshift(tmpArray);
  return array.join(' ');
}
```

к примеру, если n = 27, то выводит 2,3,5 7 11 13 17 19 23

Почему первые числа с запятой?

Comment: А где ВАШИ попытки написать код?

Comment: миллиарды миллионов, никак не получается

Comment: Это не отменяет необходимости показать созданный код и точно указать, где и какая проблема возникла, чтобы можно было подсказать, как с ней бороться. За Вас тут никто код не напишет - чай, не бюро добрых услуг.

Comment: исправил, простите за ошибку

Comment: Нет, серьезно... вы додумались скопировать чужой код из интернета: https://overcoder.net/q/255515/сито-алгоритма-эратосфена-в-javascript-работает-бесконечно-для-большого-числа и при этом не додумались найти и взять чужой ответ... который есть на той же странице. Переходы по меткам `continue removeMultiples` уже сто лет никто не учит делать, чтобы это было простым совпадением.

Comment: все равно большое спасибо

Comment: @proger не за что, но можно же было быть хоть немного более самостоятельным в этом плане и попробовать другие варианты)) А так это как раз причина, по которой мы требуем от делающих домашние задания привести свои попытки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function filter(number) {
  let arr = Array.from({length: number - 1}, (_, i) => i + 2);

  function helper(arr) {
    if (!arr[0] || arr[0] ** 2 > number) {return arr}
      return [arr[0], ...helper(arr.filter((element) => element % arr[0]))];
  }

  return helper(arr);
}

console.log(filter(10).join(' '));
console.log(filter(20).join(' '));
console.log(filter(100).join(' '));
console.log(filter(1000).join(' '));
```